# Using wordpress database details for login purposes

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

How can I import data from an Excel file into a database for Wordpress?

I would like to use this data for login purposes. e.g. I have an existing member that I'd like my Wordpress site to log in with his/her email, without having to register on the site again.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to import `excel, csv` file into the database. Just convert the file according to the table structure and import that file into your database.

[Reference](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/exporting-and-importing-data-between-mysql-and-microsoft-excel.php)